# How to find out who is starting a service?

Tags: windows-service

In one of our servers, SQL Server service though set to manual and its dependant services are stopped, still it starts automatically if we stop the SQL Server service.

Is there a utility or way to find out who or which service is starting SQL Server Service?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the System event log for Event ID 7035 from source Service Control Manager. This should tell you when the service was started and by whom.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I see that in event ID 7035, source is always "Service Control Manager" but we don't have any of the dependant service running still SQL Server starts automatically. Any other tip?

Comment: The event log source is always Service Control Manager. You need to look in the text of the log entry to see what security principal issued the start command.